# Netbeans 8.0.1 PHPCake auto completion

Tags: php, netbeans, ide, netbeans-8, cakephp-2.5

I have problem with auto completion and overriding methods by inserting them. I am pretty sure that earlier on i could easily Alt+Insert methods from extended classes. Now after last update they are gone. Is any one experiencing same issue? Maybe I should make some settings correction.

Comment: What update do you mean?

Comment: I noticed updates in notifications section, so I assume I had 8.0 now I have 8.0.1 Can't tell what exactly. I've update my question with Netbeans version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround is to delete your cache directory:

- open NetBeans->Help->About to find location of cache directory
- close NetBeans
- remove the cache directory
- start NetBeans again

For details see [this NetBeans issue](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=247026)